# Draw UIView based on CGPoint on screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have four small circles on screen in a random position. These small circles could be anywhere on the screen and are in front on a MapView.

[image]

How can I create a shape based on those circles ?

[image]

Also, the user can press a Button to randomly change the position of the circles, so the shape have to recreated.

[image]

So far, I'm reading about UIBezierPath and I'm able to create a shape based on points but I can't doing dinamically.

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(52, 33)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(145, 19)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(158, 79)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(66, 103)];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
```

Comment: You should take a closer look to Core Graphics tutorials, like this one : http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients
The `CGContextRef` object would help you to achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you Randy for your response. I read the tutorial, but still I'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is adding a `UIImageView` with a transparent background color as a subview of your `MapView` ( the image view should have the same frame as your map view ).

In `viewDidLoad`, you can begin an imageContext, using :

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)`

Then, you can draw lines between your points, using `CGMutablePath` :

```
func drawLines()
    {
        let point1 = CGPointMake(20, 100)
        let point2 = CGPointMake(230, 150)
        let point3 = CGPointMake(40, 340)

        let points = [point1, point2, point3]

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextClearRect(context, self.imageView.frame)

        let pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();

        for var i = 0; i < points.count; i++
        {
            let point = points[i]

            if i == 0
            {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, point.x, point.y)
            }
            else
            {
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, point.x, point.y)
            }
        }

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef)
        CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.brownColor().CGColor)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
```

Of course, you should adapt this method to your needs, but this would work dynamically.

It's not the only solution. If you want to get to know Core Graphics a bit more, you should read some documentation. It can be pretty powerful.